# How to invert the colors of a ggmap raster image in R?

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, ggmap, r-raster

I'm assuming the [Raster package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/vignettes/Raster.pdf) has what I need... I'm simply wanting to invert the colors in a Raster image.

The actual scenario is this: I want to invert the raster image returned by a [ggmap](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap) call:

```
 library(ggmap)
 ggmap(get_stamenmap(maptype = "toner"))
```

[image: Regular toner map]

I want to invert the colors to get a white-on-black version of the Stamen Toner map:

[image: Inverted toner map]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This inverts the `raster` object returned by `get_stamenmap()`

```
library("ggmap")
m <- get_stamenmap(maptype = "toner")

# invert colors in raster
invert <- function(x) rgb(t(255-col2rgb(x))/255)    
m_inv <- as.raster(apply(m, 2, invert))

# copy attributes from original object
class(m_inv) <- class(m)
attr(m_inv, "bb") <- attr(m, "bb")

ggmap(m_inv)
```

[image: ggmap inverted]